# MS Visual Web Developer Double click VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

MS Visual Web Developer 2010-VB.Net

When button is **double clicked** ,i want to show some controls.How to add codes in double click event.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks.For CMS ..Which is best ..MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express Edition or Visual Studio

Comment: Full blown Visual Studio is always a lot better (albeit a lot less free). Oh and please check an answer as accepted if the solution was useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact that you're using Visual Studio Web Developer, I'll assume you're doing something with a browser. If you're not, comment on the answer and I'll delete it.

ASP.Net doesn't distinguish between single and double clicks. You'll have to use Javascript for this. To do what you're trying to accomplish, you'll have to make a client-side button whose `ondblclick` event calls the `.click()` function of the server-side button's rendered `<input>` element. Here's what I mean:

```
<asp:Button Id="Button" OnClick="Some_Method()" />
<!-- This renders to something like this: -->
<input type="submit" onclick="..." name="Button" id="Button" />
```

Knowing this (you can check this in your rendered document), you can do this:

```
<input type="button" ondblclick="document.getElementById('Button').click()" ... />
```

Of course, you probably only want one button visible. To do this, simply set `Visible` to `false` in the ASP.Net server control.

Again, this question could be for non-ASP.Net stuff, in which case this answer is worthless. If so, comment telling me so, and I'll delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this purely in client side.

Add client-side button that has "ondblclick" event to your ASPX/HTML page:

```
<button ondblclick="showControls()">Show Controls</button>
```

Add a DIV with display style set to none. Place your controls inside of that DIV:

```
<div id="myControls" style="display:none">
    My<br>
    Control<br>
    are<br>
    placed<br>
    here<br>
</div>
```

Add client-side code that unhides that DIV:

```
<script>
    function showControls(){
        document.getElementById("myControls").style.display=""
     }
</script>
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5haxS/